# Understanding alternating linear form

Tags: linear-algebra

let $V$ be a vector space over $K$. An n-linear form on $V$ is a fuction $f:V^n\rightarrow K$ such that for all $i=1,2,..,n$ and $u_1,...,u_{i-1},v,u_{i+1},..,u_n\in V$, the fuction

$\begin{align*} & V\rightarrow K\\ & v\rightarrow f(u_1,..,u_{i-1},v,u_{i+1},..,u_n)\end{align*}$

is linear.

Definition. We say that $f$ is *alternating* if $f(u_1,..,u_n)=0$ whenever $v_i=v_j$ for some $i\neq j$.

Example. In this function, assume $v_1=v_2$. Others are not equal. Then $f$ is alternating, right? 
Example. Again in this function, assume $v_1\neq v_2$. Others are eqal. Then, $f$ is alternating, right?

Can you check these examples?

Comment: What can we check, if you don't say how $f$ is defined?

Comment: @Bernard $f:V^n\rightarrow K$ such that for all $i=1,2,..,n$ and $u_1,...,u_{i-1},v,u_{i+1},..,u_n\in V$, the fuction 

$\begin{align*} & V\rightarrow K\\ & v\rightarrow f(u_1,..,u_{i-1},v,u_{i+1},..,u_n)\end{align*}$

Comment: This doesn't tell me how the function is defined. You only stated  a property it *should* have.

Comment: In your definition of alternating, what are $v_i$ and $v_j$? These quantities have not been introduced.

Comment: @littleO these should be $u_i$ and $u_j$.